# Using make Static Pattern Rules for multiple files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm having trouble creating a pattern to apply to every file in a subdirectory

I have the following tree:

- libft/
- ..makefile
- ..obj/
- ..bonus/
- ........bonusfile1.c
- ........bonusfile2.c
- ........bonusfile3.c
- ........[...etc...]
- ..mainfile1.c
- ..mainfile2.c
- ..mainfile3.c
- ..[...etc...]

I'm trying to compile the `bonus/bonusfiles` into the objects `obj` directory but no mater what I type I'm coming up short of my objective.

My makefile:

```
SRC_FILES=  ft_atoi.c       \
            ft_bzero.c      \
            ...

BONUS_FILES=ft_lstadd_back.c    \
            ft_lstadd_front.c   \
            ...

NAME=libft.a

LIBSO=libft.so

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

BONUS_DIR=bonus/

OBJ_DIR=obj/

HDR_NAME=libft.h

BONUS_HDR=_bonus.h

SRC_PATH=$(addprefix $(SRC_DIR), $(SRC_FILES))

BONUS_PATH=$(addprefix $(BONUS_DIR), $(BONUS_FILES))

SRC_NAMES=${SRC_FILES:.c=.o}

BONUS_NAMES=${BONUS_FILES:.c=.o}

SRC_NAMES_O=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(SRC_NAMES))

BONUS_NAMES_O=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(BONUS_NAMES))

HDR= $(addprefix $(HDR_DIR),$(HDR_NAME))

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR) $(SRC_NAMES)
    ar -rc $@ $(SRC_NAMES_O)
    ranlib $@

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)$@ 

bonus: $(BONUS_PATH)
    ar -r $(NAME) $(BONUS_NAMES_O)
    ranlib $@

$(BONUS_PATH): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)$@
    
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm -rf src/*.o
    rm -rf *.o

sclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME) $(LIBSO) a.out

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

so:
    $(CC) -nostartfiles -fPIC $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_FILES) $(BONUS_PATH)
    gcc -nostartfiles -shared -o libft.so $(SRC_FILES) $(BONUS_PATH)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re so bonus
```

What I wanted to do was something similar to the `%.o: %.c` target but I can't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make Rule #1: your recipe should _always_ build a target named exactly `$@`.  Never `../$@` or `$(OBJ_DIR)$@` or anything else.  Only `$@`.  If you work backward from that requirement, it means that if you want to build a file that goes in a specific place, you have to define the target of the rule (the part on the left of the `:`) to be exactly the thing you want, not some other path.

Comment: Why are your targets, like `$(NAME)`, depending on `$(SRC_NAMES)`, when what your recipe for that target actually uses is `$(SRC_NAMES_O)`?  Your target should depend on the files the recipe actually uses.

Comment: Similar for `bonus`?

Comment: @MadScientist It's my first time making a makefile I just made a bunch of vars that I thought I'd use and built the targets as I went along

Comment: I recommend reading the GNU make manual, at least the first few chapters, to understand the concepts behind a makefile: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html